# SQL table joining different people

Tags: sql, join

I join two tables showing different information about a population but in table zp there are some people which are not shown in wg. So I would like to add also these people from zp to the final table, but in the columns where there is no information, I would like to have zeros.

```
SELECT *  FROM mobility.mzmv2010.wegeinland wg
JOIN mobility.mzmv2010.zielpersonen zp USING ("HHNR","ZIELPNR")
```

An example can be seen in the picture:

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want a `left join` . . . with the person table first:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(zp."WP" * "w_rdist")/(62868 * AVG(zp."WP")), 0)
FROM mobility.mzmv2010.zielpersonen zp LEFT JOIN
     mobility.mzmv2010.wegeinland wg
     USING ("HHNR", "ZIELPNR") ;
```

Note:  You should qualify the `w_rdist` column to specify what table it is coming from.

Comment: The problem is  when I write          SELECT *  FROM mobility.mzmv2010.wegeinland wg
JOIN mobility.mzmv2010.zielpersonen zp USING ("HHNR","ZIELPNR")     I still don't see the missing lines

Comment: You say left join, but do (inner) join.